# C# MVC - Using LIKE in LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to display names from a SQL database that ends with certain char but it won't let me use WildCard in the Controller ActionResult.

This is my current code that I want to work.

```
public ActionResult GetClients()
    {
        MyDBEntities myDBEntites = new MyDBEntities();
        var clients = from c in myDBEntites.Client
                      where c.name LIKE '%r'
                      select c;
        return View(clients);

    }
```

What am I missing here for it to work? If its not working with wild card then how do I get the names that ends with a specific char?

Comment: Can't do `LIKE` in LINQ AFAIK. Do `WHERE c.name.EndsWith("r")`

Comment: @apokryfos thank you! i wonder why WildCard didnt work, i mean its like a complete SQL code except from wildcard. weird.

Comment: LINQ is similar but not the same as SQL . It's simply different query languages. The compiler will convert LINQ to SQL as best it can when performing queries so I wouldn't be surprised if `.EndsWith` actually gets converted to `LIKE` in SQL.

Comment: @apokryfos Ahh ok i get it now. Thank you so much man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIKE` is a SQL keyword, therefore you could use [`EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
c.name.EndsWith("r");
```

As a best practice, you may want to consider wrapping your DBEntities within a `using` block so it is correctly disposed. You could also move it into a new method/service layer, rather than retrieving it within the Controller which would be a cleaner approach.

**Service Layer**

```
public IEnumerable<Client> RetrieveClients(string endString)
{
   using (MyDBEntities myDbEntities = new MyDBEntities()) 
   {
        var clients = from c in myDBEntites.Client
                      where c.name.EndsWith(endString)'
                      select c;

        return clients;
   }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetClients()
{
    var clients = RetrieveClients("R");
    return View(clients);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `EndsWith`

```
public ActionResult GetClients()
    {
        MyDBEntities myDBEntites = new MyDBEntities();
        var clients = from c in myDBEntites.Client
                      where c.name.EndsWith("r")
                      select c;
        return View(clients);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest you to do here is to try to solve this with `String.EndsWith` ([LINK TO DOCUMENTATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx)) method.

Let me write an example based on your question, using linq ofcourse:

```
public ActionResult GetClients()
{
  MyDBEntities myDBEntites = new MyDBEntities();
  var clients = from c in myDBEntites.Client
                where c.name.EndsWith("r")
            select c;

 return View(clients);
}
```

Comment: @Dolev if you've found this answer useful please let me know :)